# Trace Back Error in Python Code for Calculator

Tags: python, regex, traceback

So, i'm working on making a calculator in python(I am relatively new) and, after doing some reading I found out about the re.sub thing. The problem I am having is that every time I run the program it runs a trackback error in line 9. If any one knows how to do this any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```py
import re
#The input should be an equation, for example 26 +(32-1).
a = input("Enter Equation:")
c = "("
#It is supposed to look for parenthesis and make a sub-string out of whats in it
if '(' and ')' in a:
  a = re.sub(r'^[^(]+(','',a)
  print(a)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
> a = re.sub(r'^[^(]+(','',a)
> missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 6
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [this article on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, please add the  expected input, output, and stack trace to your question.

Comment: Is this your full code?  I only see 7 lines, so not sure what would be in line 9.

Comment: Yes, I just started and, wanted to go via PEMDOS.

Comment: @user1558604 python includes comments in line counts

Comment: @user1558604 I added the comments in to make it easier to understand for this.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: it should be `if '(' in a and ')' in a:`.

Answer (score 0):

Within a regex, you have to escape the parenthesis because they have special meaning :

```
a = re.sub(r'^[^(]+\(','',a)
```